# Unable to find the format of the input time

Tags: go, time

I am creating a Go application in which users can input the time in any format as below:

```
Default Layout:  2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001

US Layout:       November 10, 2009

ISO Layout:      2020-02-10

UNIX Time:       1581422196084
```

Is there any way to find out the format of the input time? The only thing I can find is how to convert the time from one format to other but there is nothing around finding the existing time format.

One possible way I can think of is adding a regex for all the time formats. However, before implementing it I wanted to make sure there is no Go method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide what layouts need to be supported out of the Go layouts ( https://programming.guide/go/format-parse-string-time-date-example.html ) :

```
    ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
    UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
    RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
    RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
    RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
    RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
    RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
    Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
    // Handy time stamps.
    Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
    StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
    StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
    StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
```

And there is a function called :
time.Parse(layout, value string) (Time, error) where error is not nil if the input time does not support the layout

Say, I want to support ANSIC and UnixDate, I can do the following :

```
t, err := time.Parse(time.ANSIC, inputTime)
if err == nil {
return t
}

t, err = time.Parse(time.UnixDate, inputTime)
if err == nil {
return t
}
```

Obviously, some code optimisations in the code structure can be done here but this will be way more efficient than using regex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RahulSatal
If it helped, Can you upvote and accept the answer ? 

Thanks,

Comment: I am getting an error with that code - https://play.golang.org/p/C_JR6xPcEdy

Comment: Hey @RahulSatal , this ought to work, time is a reserved word, have edited my answer :
https://play.golang.org/p/J4leTDcGcAM

Hope it helps.